# Remove margin on column over certain breakpoint

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve a layout in Tailwind similar to Bootstrap where one of my columns inside a Container has no auto margin. Example of the CSS in bootstrap. Can anyone offer a similar workaround in Tailwind?

```
@media (min-width: 994px) {
    .section-full-width-right > .container > .row > .col-lg-6:last-child {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@screen md {
  .section-full-width-right > .container > .row > .col-lg-6:last-child {
    @apply absolute left-half;
  }
}
```

And make sure you change your inset attribute into

```
inset: {
  0: "0",
  auto: "auto",
  half: "50%"
}
```

in the tailwind.config.js file.